# Number of intersection points of 2 conics in n variables (quadrics)?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, quadrics

Consider $n$ variables $X = \{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Consider two 2nd degree equations over X:

$$P_k^2(x) = a_0^{(k)} + \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{(k)} x_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij}^{(k)} x_ix_j = 0 $$ for $k \in \{ 1, 2 \}$ s.t. $a^k_{ij} \neq 0$ for some i,j.

What is the maximum no. of points of intersection of $P_1^2(x)$ and $P_2^2(x)$, assuming that no $P_k^2(x)$ is contained in some proper subspace of span($X$), where span($X$) is a vector space over field $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $n$.

I know that if $n = 2$, then we get two conics, we have at most 4 points of intersection. Also if we don't put the condition that $P_k^2(x)$ is not contained in some proper subspace of span($X$), then we can easily see there are infinite points of intersection for the following polynomials over 4 variables: $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $u^2 + v^2 = 4$.

**Edit**. On googling, I was able to find this : [http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/3folds/qu.pdf](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasda/3folds/qu.pdf)
However, I am not able to understand the math here. Can anyone just post the final results if they understand it (if it is related).

Comment: $x^2+y^2=4$ isn't contained in a proper linear subspace of a 4-dimensional real vector space. Did you perhaps mean something else?

Comment: Quadrics is the term when $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @KReiser Oh yes, informally I mean: let the 'maximal projection' of the equation $C = x^2 + y^2 = 4$ over 4 variables be the curve $C' = x^2 + y^2 = 4$ over 2 variables x and y where $C(x,y,u,v) = \forall u v C'(x,y)$. Then the condition should be that the 'maximal projection' of any equation is not contained in a proper subspace of span(X). I don't know how to say this formally.

Comment: The point is that $C$ is a quadric hypersurface, not at all a curve. I would call it a higher-dimensional cylinder.